# how to awoid duplication ajax call in composite component

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, composite-component

May be I make a fundamental mistake about jsf 2.2 specification, if so I would like to learn the correct solution of my problem. I use mojarra 2.2.9 immplementation, primemafaces 5.0.

I have a composite component with input, which always process on change event:

```
<cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="value" type="java.lang.String" required="true"/>
    <cc:clientBehavior name="change" event="change" targets="input"/>
</cc:interface>

<cc:implementation>
    <span id="#{cc.clientId}">
    <p:inputText value="#{cc.attrs.value}">
        <p:ajax update="@this"/>
    </p:inputText>
/* some ather component */
    </span>        
</cc:implementation>
```

And now in some cases I want to use additional listener and update some component outside cc, like clientBehavior solution:

```
<my:inp value="#{bean.value}">
<p:ajax event="change" listener="#{bean.listener}" update="someComponentOnPage" process="@this">
</my:inp>
```

Using that solution, I have 2 ajax call on 1 change event: first inside cc, second outside. Is there a solution to call ajax only once (if exist clientBehavior then not use ajax that inside)?

P.S.: sorry for my english...

Comment: So you want to sort of "merge" the two AJAX calls, presumably for performance reasons or something like that?

Comment: @DavidS, yes, merge or ignore ajax inside composite component if exist clientBehavior.